# Add Member to Office 365 group with JSON/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add a user who clicks on a button in a SharePoint (online) site to a Office 365 group. I know this can be done via JSON using the Add Member API.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members.md

I am however really inexperienced when it comes to JSON and keep messing up the POST function. This is the code I have currently, everything before the comma has been working fine.

```
function showButton() {

    $('btn-1').on('click', function(event) {
        var userProfileProperties
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
        userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
        clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

        function onSuccess(){
            accountProperties = userProfileProperties.get_userProfileProperties();
            accountId = accountProperties['msOnline-ObjectId'];
            //JSON Query
            jQuery.ajax({   
                url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/groups/groupID/members/$ref";
                method: "POST";
                contentType: "application/json";
                dataType: 'json',
                {
                    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/" + accountId
                };
            });
        };  
        function onFail(){
            alert(failed);
        };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your document , you will find authentication token is required in the Request headers .Without authentication token ,you will receive an error as :

```
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "Bearer access token is empty."
```

As a solution , you could try following steps :

1.Register a javascript Application in Azure AD and configure your app to allow the OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow.Tokens are obtained using the OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow. Using implicit grant, your application requests an access token from Azure AD for the currently signed-in user by sending the user to an authorization URL where the user signs in with their Office 365 credentials and then is redirected back to the app with the access token in the URL .

2.Add permissions to Graph API .

3.Add an html page to your sharepoint online(using Explorer mode) .

4.Edit the html , write below function to get an access token:

```
 function requestToken() { 
   // Change clientId and replyUrl to reflect your app's values 
   // found on the Configure tab in the Azure Management Portal. 
   // Also change {your_subdomain} to your subdomain for both endpointUrl and resource. 
   var clientId = '3dadb44e-feaa-4158-90f5-e129e15db66d';//ID of your App in Azure
   var replyUrl = 'https://o365e3w15.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/app.html';  //my sharepoint page that requests 
   //an oauth 2 authentification and data
   //It is also referenced in the REPLY URL field of my App in Azure
   var endpointUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages';
   var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
   var authServer  = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?';  
   //var authServer  =  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?';//this works either
   var responseType = 'token'; 

   var url = authServer + 
        "response_type=" + encodeURI(responseType) + "&" + 
        "client_id=" + encodeURI(clientId) + "&" + 
        "resource=" + encodeURI(resource) + "&" + 
        "redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(replyUrl); 

   window.location = url; 
}
```

5. After that ,you could make an ajax call to graph api endpoint to get/post request, for example, get current user's messages:

   ```
   var endpointUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages";

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   xhr.open("GET", endpointUrl); 
   var myToken = getToken();
   // The APIs require an OAuth access token in the Authorization header, formatted like this: 
   //'Authorization: Bearer <token>'. 
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + myToken); 

   // Process the response from the API.  
   xhr.onload = function () { 
     if (xhr.status == 200) { 
       //alert('data received');
       var message="";
       var object = JSON.parse(xhr.response); 
       for(i=0;i<object.value.length;i++){
       message+='Subject: ' + object.value[i].subject + '<br>';    
      }
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = message;
     } else { } 
   }
   // Make request.
   xhr.send();
   ```
6. display this app.html into any SharePoint Webpart page by calling it within an iframe tag.

All detail steps you will find in [this article](http://mosshowto.blogspot.sg/2015/11/embed-office-group-sharepoint-online.html) , i have tested and work fine in my side .

Comment: I see how this will get the OAuth token but am having trouble calling the token for each user who accesses the page where my button is.